# "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source -:"

Tags: apt, updates, keyrings

I'm new to ubuntu and i accidently some settings in Softwares and Updates.

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-security: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Here is the list of my keyrings:

```
NEMESIS:~$ cd /usr/share/keyrings
NEMESIS:/usr/share/keyrings$ ls
ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg 
ubuntu-master-keyring.gpg  
ubuntu-pro-esm-apps.gpg        
ubuntu-pro-ros.gpg
ubuntu-archive-removed-keys.gpg   
ubuntu-pro-anbox-cloud.gpg  
ubuntu-pro-esm-infra.gpg
ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg       
ubuntu-pro-cc-eal.gpg       
ubuntu-pro-fips.gpg
ubuntu-cloudimage-removed-keys.gpg  
ubuntu-pro-cis.gpg          
ubuntu-pro-realtime-kernel.gpg
```

Please help me!!